# How to sort a List grouped by another field

Tags: c#, .net

I have a list of event objects:

```
class Event {
    private int eventId;
    private int categoryId;
    private int eventOrder;
}
```

After ordering by the eventOrder field, this is the result:

```
Event (eventId = 11, categoryId = 3, eventOrder = 1) 
Event (eventId = 44, categoryId = 2, eventOrder = 2)
Event (eventId = 33, categoryId = 3, eventOrder = 3)
Event (eventId = 55, categoryId = 4, eventOrder = 4)
Event (eventId = 22, categoryId = 1, eventOrder = 5)
```

If I order by eventOrder and then by categoryId, the result is:

```
Event (eventId = 55, categoryId = 4, eventOrder = 4) 
Event (eventId = 11, categoryId = 3, eventOrder = 1)  
Event (eventId = 33, categoryId = 3, eventOrder = 3) 
Event (eventId = 22, categoryId = 2, eventOrder = 5) 
Event (eventId = 44, categoryId = 1, eventOrder = 2)
```

I need to respect the lower eventOrder to order the events, but the categories need to be consecutive, expected result:

```
Event (eventId = 11, categoryId = 3, eventOrder = 1) 
Event (eventId = 33, categoryId = 3, eventOrder = 3)
Event (eventId = 44, categoryId = 1, eventOrder = 2)
Event (eventId = 55, categoryId = 4, eventOrder = 4)
Event (eventId = 22, categoryId = 2, eventOrder = 5)
```

In summary: the events need to be ordered by the lowest eventOrder within the category.
Can I achieve that with a comparator?

Comment: You can do that with Linq `OrderByDescending` and `ThenBy`

Comment: I have edited the question to clarify, i cant order the list by categoryId after ordering ir by eventOrder, i need to only move the position of matching categoryIds

Comment: If I order by eventOrder and then by categoryId, the result is:

`Event (eventId = 55, categoryId = 4, eventOrder = 4)`

`Event (eventId = 11, categoryId = 3, eventOrder = 1) `

`Event (eventId = 33, categoryId = 3, eventOrder = 3)`

`Event (eventId = 22, categoryId = 2, eventOrder = 5)`

`Event (eventId = 44, categoryId = 1, eventOrder = 2)`

Comment: I think I understand your question now. Sorry for having marked it as a dupe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to group by `categoryId` and then sort by the smallest `eventOrder` in each group. I also added a secondary sort on `categoryId` but that is only needed if  `eventOrder` is not unique. After the sort you can unflatten the grouping with a `SelectMany`.

```
var eventList = new List<Event>
{
    new Event {eventId = 11, categoryId = 3, eventOrder = 1},
    new Event {eventId = 44, categoryId = 2, eventOrder = 2},
    new Event {eventId = 33, categoryId = 3, eventOrder = 3},
    new Event {eventId = 55, categoryId = 4, eventOrder = 4},
    new Event {eventId = 22, categoryId = 1, eventOrder = 5}
};
var sortedResult = eventList.GroupBy(x => x.categoryId)
    .OrderBy(x => x.Min(y => y.eventOrder))
    .ThenBy(x => x.Key)
    .SelectMany(x => x)
    .ToList();

foreach (var item in sortedResult)
  Console.WriteLine($"Event (eventId = {item.eventId}, categoryId = {item.categoryId}, eventOrder = {item.eventOrder})");
```

Output:

```
Event (eventId = 11, categoryId = 3, eventOrder = 1)
Event (eventId = 33, categoryId = 3, eventOrder = 3)
Event (eventId = 44, categoryId = 2, eventOrder = 2)
Event (eventId = 55, categoryId = 4, eventOrder = 4)
Event (eventId = 22, categoryId = 1, eventOrder = 5)
```